# How does compiler handle exceptions that are implicit? Looking for design strategies

Tags: c++, exceptions, compiler

Throughout the function handleException, the exception encountered is implicit. How does the compiler handle such implicit passing of exceptions? [For e.g. in C++ methods, **this** pointer is passed to account for the current object. My question is how does a compiler handle exceptions internally - handleException has no arguments.]

```
 void handleException()
 {
   try {
     throw;
   }
   catch (MyException& e) {
     ...code to handle MyException...
   }
   catch (YourException& e) {
     ...code to handle YourException...
   }
 }

 void f()
 {
   try {
     ...something that might throw...
   }
   catch (...) {
     handleException();
   }
 }
```

Comment: That's now how it is used in C++. You need to ask on SO how the throw clause works. I have not come across a language that has the concept of implicit exceptions (I suppose they could exist). The better question is why would you want such a concept, it seems very error prone in its usage.

Comment: @Martin: That is one way it is used in C++, see C++03 §15.1p6.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: From n3225. 15.1p8<quote>A throw-expression with no operand rethrows the currently handled exception.</quote>15.1p9<quote>If no exception is presently being handled, executing a throw-expression with no operand calls std::terminate()</quote>. So No. There is NEVER an implicit exception that is thrown.

Comment: @Martin: Where is the exception mentioned in the `throw;` statement?  If it is not mentioned, is that not implicit?  It sounds like you are forming an opinion based on the title alone without actually reading the question body, which explicitly mentions what the OP means by "implicit" (which is also not a term used in the standard).

Comment: @Martin York: it's a construct that ideally would be used to *translate* exceptions when you're using two or more libraries with non-standard exceptions. It never got into general use, I think mostly because earlier (when such libraries abounded) Visual C++ compilers had a bug that caused exception object's destructor to be called twice for this construct. And nowadays libraries just use standard exceptions, so generally no need. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Fred Nurk: The OP indicates that `throw;` operates on `this pointer`. Which is just not true. It operates on the currently handled exception (nothing implicit about that).

Comment: @Martin: Where does he indicate that?

Comment: @Fred Nurk: <quote>[For e.g. in C++ methods, **this** pointer is passed to account for the current object.</quote>

Comment: @Martin: How is that wrong? The "this" pointer is used for the "current object".  Where does that mention "throw;" or exceptions at all?  Did you read the very next sentence, which shows he's *not* assuming a particular implementation and is instead asking how they are implemented?

Comment: @Fred Nurk: That's not how I read the sentence. He is implying that the this pointer is used in the throw for C++. The "For example" is extending the previous sentence.

Comment: @Martin: Re-read it.  You even quoted the initial bracket above, that may help you tie those two clauses together so you can understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Pay no attention to that man behind the curtain.

Because the compiler knows how it implements exceptions, it can use that internal information.  The simplest way is to use a global (or thread local) variable to store info about any "active" exception; then retrieve that, mostly to get type info, and propagate.  C++0x partially exposes this information with std::exception_ptr; see §18.8.5 in N3225.

Exceptions are handled differently from parameters; analogy to "this" won't be helpful.  The value for "this" is usually treated as a normal pointer parameter, except for being hidden from the user behind the curtain.